# How do I render a shiny metallic or chromed material?

Tags: materials

I really thought I got this but I can't seem to get this material right.

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]   [image]

In case, anyone wants to see more photos of this, it's the Dior foundation cap.

But I cant seem to get it to shine like this.

Although I've tried various nodes, this is what I'm doing currently:

[image]

And this is what I'm getting:

[image]

My roughness for the above image is at 0.192 and reducing it further isn't looking great. I've also tried using principal BSDF with metallic at 1 but that didn't look similar to what I want either.

This is the HDRI I'm using: https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=studio&h=photo_studio_01

Any tips on how to come closer to the reference images would be really appreciated!

Edit for Jachym:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your HDRI doesn't have enough contrast.

1. Use default *Principled BSDF* shader with *Metallic = 1*, and *Roughness = 0.1*
2. Add a [contrasty HDRI](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=venice_sunset)
3. Done.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this HDRI really made a difference. Thank you! However, now I have a pink/ purple tint on the metallic surface, do you make a box around this to reduce its influence?

Comment: Hey :). I simply lowered the camera a bit, and used the Camera Y shift to compensate. But that's more about [general photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) and less about Blender :).

Comment: I'm sorry if this is very basic but lowering the camera certainly changes the reflections but how do you make them black and white? The colour of my background seems to have changed to a hue of pink as well (adding a screenshot in my original post at the end if you have time to see it)

Comment: Sure :). Simply add a *Hue/Saturation* node after your HDRI and lower Saturation to 0 :). You can also increase the contrast with a Contrast node.

Comment: I've always been a bit wary of nodes but this was relatively easy. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project :)

Comment: Also, if you want the reflection lines nice and straight, use a long lens (200-300mm) :)

Comment: Thanks again for all your help and tips, theybe been super helpful!